# Get the current exception in blazor Error Boundary

Tags: c#, exception, logging, blazor, .net-6.0

I have an exception that has been generated in a certain context of my application.
I would like to be able to collect it, send it to the logger and recover the previous state.
[image: Scenario]

The problem is that this error-bound exception cannot be accessed since its current exception property is protected.
[image]

What would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to be able to collect it send it to the logger and recover the previous state.

Create a component as below (Error.razor):

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
@inject ILogger<Error> Logger
@inject IJSRuntime jsRuntime

<CascadingValue Value="this">
@ChildContent
</CascadingValue>    
@code {
[Parameter]
public RenderFragment? ChildContent { get; set; }

public void ProcessError(Exception ex)
{
    Logger.LogError("Error:ProcessError - Type: {Type} Message: {Message}",
        ex.GetType(), ex.Message);
    jsRuntime.ToastrError("An Error has occured!"); 
    //StateHasChanged();       
}
```

}

`Error` component can log errors using the Blazor built-in logger and display JavaScript error messages with [Toastr](https://github.com/CodeSeven/toastr) through the `ProcessError` method. Obviously, other loggers such as Serilog, Elmah and even other custom loggers can be used to log in this method.

`StateHasChanged` will be used when the error handling method wants to directly intervene in the rendering of the user interface of the component where an exception occurred. For example, when we want to make a change in the rendered elements of the page after an error (change the color of a button or the font color of a label or text box or...).

Now, we edit the `App.razor` component as follows:

```
<Error>
    <Router ...>
        ...
    </Router>
</Error>
```

In fact, we enclose the Router component by our own custom component (Error.razor) so that the Error component is cascaded to any program component that considers Error as `[CascadingParameter]`.

Now, it is enough to process errors as follows in other components:

```
@code {
    [CascadingParameter]
    public Error? Error { get; set; }

    private void CreatePost()
    {
        try
        {
           throw new InvalidOperationException("a message!");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Error?.ProcessError(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, the Error component is defined as a `CascadingParameter` and in a try catch block, the `ProcessError` method of the Error component is called and the issued exception is sent to it. In my example, the Error component has only one error handling method. Obviously, this component can have several other custom error handling methods for different purposes.

To save the logs in a text file on the servers, you can use Serilog, the method of which is explained [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/log-data-into-file-using-serilog-framework-in-blazor-server-app/). You can also save the logs to a Database with a [custom log provider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmFsQJBbsO0).

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it requires explicit error-handling, while the ErrorBoundary would automatically catch unhandled exceptions. Are there any advantaged of this method that I'm missing?

Comment: The advantage of this approach is that exceptions can be logged somewhere (database or text file).

Comment: Same thing can be achieved with `ErrorBoundary.OnErrorAsync`.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem and after investigating the source code it was easy to get the current exception from ErrorContent of the ErrorBoundary.

```
<ErrorBoundary>
                    <ChildContent>
                        @Body
                    </ChildContent>
                    <ErrorContent Context="Exception">
                        <div>
                             @Exception.Message<br/>
                        </div>
                    </ErrorContent>
                </ErrorBoundary>
```

Get the current exception from the Context (RenderFragment) of ErrorContent (see above code example).

ErrorBoundaryBase ->

```
/// <summary>
    /// The content to be displayed when there is an error.
    /// </summary>
    [Parameter] public RenderFragment<Exception>? ErrorContent { get; set; }
```

Comment: The custom class from accepted answer is ok, but this is easiest solution. Thank you.

Comment: This works for me, except `@Exception.InnerException` doesn't have anything... no stack trace data.  If I throw an exception in my service, all I get is the exception message text, nothing indicating at which method/line the exception occurred.

Answer (score 6):

The CurrentException property is protected, not private, so you can define this class:

```
public class MyErrorBoundary : ErrorBoundary
{
    public new Exception? CurrentException => base.CurrentException;
}
```

and then replace ErrorBoundary with MyErrorBoundary in all your code. Voilà.

EDIT: Here is an example of how I use MyErrorBoundary in my file ContainerWithExceptionHandling.razor:

```
@code {
    [Parameter(CaptureUnmatchedValues = true)]
    public Dictionary<string, object> Attributes { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public RenderFragment ChildContent { get; set; }

    private MyErrorBoundary boundary;
}

<div @attributes="Attributes">
    <ExceptionBoundary @ref="boundary">
        <ChildContent>
            @ChildContent
        </ChildContent>
        <ErrorContent>
            <ExceptionView Exception="@boundary.CurrentException"
                HowToResume="(() => boundary.Recover())" />
        </ErrorContent>
    </ExceptionBoundary>
</div>
```

In this example, ExceptionView is a custom component that displays an Exception's message in a box with a Resume button.

My MainLayout.razor has:

```
<ContainerWithExceptionHandling class="content px-4">
    @Body
</ContainerWithExceptionHandling>
```

This way, if a component of a web page throws an error message when it's rendered, then the main section of the page will be replaced by an easy-to-read error message, and it will be relatively easy to resume normal operation.

Comment: How can I use the Exception in my Error page?

Comment: I came to the same conclusion and I was surprised it actually worked. Why would MS restrict access to the Exception in the first place?

Comment: @Aulimaitar This looks like a really neat solution, but How would you use it? Suppose I wanted to show some sort of message when an exception occurred. I can't see how you get hold of `CurrentException` in the markup where you use this component. Or am I misunderstanding the point here?

Comment: @AvrohomYisroel You get hold of CurrentException by using an `@ref` to get hold of the component MyErrorBoundary. I've edited my original answer to illustrate this for you.